# Are ES2015 typed arrays allocated inside the runtime heap?

Tags: javascript, typed-arrays

Are ES2015 typed arrays allocated inside the runtime heap?

Or is it left to implementation?

If I understand correctly, Node.js `Buffer` instances are allocated outside the runtime heap ([source](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer): "A `Buffer` is similar to an array of integers but corresponds to a raw memory allocation outside the V8 heap").

Comment: Could you provide some links to docs to support your statement? (i.e. a link to a page where the NodeJS Buffer memory allocation is discussed/explained)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ECMAScript 6 does not specify any mechanism of memory allocation.

Engines are free to implement what they want. I'd expect them to be allocated on the heap as it is the default for all objects, but they might as well go on the stack frame for optimisation purposes or in a dedicated "heap" segment with special garbage collection semantics.